# How can I speed up moving window operations on numpy vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function (drop_max) that looks for step changes in vector of values (dat) based on the minimum difference between two regions of length L1 and L2 before and after a specified gap in the data.  I am using list comprehension to identify these step changes but find the operation is relatively slow - several seconds for a vector of about 20,000 points.  As I have >10,000 vectors to inspect I would like advice on how I might speed up this operation.

I am using python 2.7 on a windows 7/64 machine

```
def drop_max(dat,L1,gap,L2):
    L0 = len(dat)
    Ltot = L1 + gap + L2
    L1s = L1 + gap
    Lhlf = Ltot/2    
    out = numpy.zeros(dat.shape)
    tmp = numpy.array([numpy.min(dat[a:a+L1]) - numpy.max(dat[(a+L1s):(a+Ltot)]) for a in numpy.arange(0,L0-Ltot)])    
    tmp[tmp<0] = 0.0
    out[Lhlf:Lhlf+len(tmp)] = tmp
    return out
```

Comment: You can find fast rolling min and max functions in [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters) and in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions).

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed, running much faster now